# How do I specify a socks5 proxy with go get using socat

Tags: http-proxy, socat, socks5-proxy

On a centos machine I want to do `go get git.address.org/123`
through a socks5 proxy.

I thought maybe using socat to make the socks5 proxy into an http and then specifying it in the command like :

`http_proxy=localhost:8080 go get git.address.org/123`

I tried many guides but I still can't understand how to use socat. And I also tested doing `http_proxy=proxy.test:8080 go get git.address.org/123` to an actual http proxy and noticed that it still tries to connect to address.org and doesn't try anything with proxy.test

Comment: I think your second attempt (with an HTTP proxy) is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385612/453851

Comment: I think I might have got it to work with this proxy I found online `http_proxy=http://185.44.231.2:34244/ https_proxy=http://185.44.231.2:34244/ ftp_proxy=http://185.44.231.2:34244/ no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1 go get -insecure git.address.org/123` but it gives me an errno=Connection refused and errno=Network is unreachable on both ipv4 and ipv6 of git.address.org (note: it's blocked in my country so if it didn't proxify maybe that's the reason)

Comment: I tested this proxy through other programs and it works, so go get isn't using it still?